# Loglinearization of first order condition

Tags: log-linearization

I am trying to loglinearize the following first order condition (FOC):

\begin{equation}
    \varrho_{t}^{E} = \mathbb{E}_{t}q_{t, t+1}\Bigl[\left(R_{k, t}^{L} - R_{t}^{D}\right) + \gamma^{L}\left(1 - \rho_{s}\right)\mathbb{E}_{t}\varrho_{t+1}^{E}\Bigr] - \frac{\kappa_{B}}{2}\left(\frac{K_{t}^{B}}{L_{t}} - \nu_{B}\right)\left(\frac{K_{t}^{B}}{L_{t}}\right)^{2}
\end{equation}

where all the symbols without a time index are constant and stady-state value of $q_{t, t+1}$ is $\beta$. I am not sure how to handle the second term on the right hand side which represents an adjustment cost. Without this adjustment cost, I can loglinearize the FOC as

\begin{equation}
\frac{\varrho^{E}}{\beta^{P}}\widehat{\varrho}^{E}_{t} - \varrho^{E}\gamma^{L}\left(1 - \rho_{s}\right)\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{\varrho}^{E}_{t+1} = \left[R^{L} - R^{D} + \varrho^{E} \gamma^{L} \left(1 - \rho_{s}\right) \right]\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1} + R^{L} \widehat{R}^{L}_{t} - R^{D}\widehat{R}^{D}_{t}
\end{equation}

Can anybody kindly advise how to proceed? Will appreciate any pointers.

[EDIT] I took a stab at this problem and log-linearized the adjustment cost (the last term) like this:

$ - \kappa_{B}\left( \frac{K^{B}}{L} - \nu_{B} \right)\left( \frac{K^{B}}{L} \right)\left( \widehat{K_{t}^{B}} - \widehat{L}_{t}\right) - \frac{\kappa_{B}}{2}\left( \frac{K^{B}}{L} \right)^{2}\left( \frac{K^{B}}{L} - \nu_{B}\right)\left( \widehat{K_{t}^{B}} - \widehat{L_{t}}\right)$

Can I please ask whether it looks correct and if there's a way to check this? Will appreciate any advice and pointers.